# Ford Fiesta 1.6 i manual 2009 - oil in water bottle

Tags: ford

Yesterday at the garage after the usual checks the petrol attendant advised me that there is oil in my car's water bottle (which looks like milky brownish something) I did not have any warning lights on the car for over heating or low water or oil nothing - what will the cause be and how much will this cost to fix?

Comment: Welcome to the site @Maritza, your question has been asked before, if you follow the link you'll see the previous question and answers. The cost of the work is hard to say, you'll need to get a quote from a reputable mechanic.

Comment: Head gasket failure is the most likely culprit here, and as @GdD mentions the linked question has some excellent advice for this situation. It's not the end of the world on these but the sooner it's addressed generally the better, it will get worse with time and if you can sort it *before* it gets to the point of over heating that make all the difference!

Comment: @motosubatsu has a good point, waiting to get this fixed will likely cost you more down the line.